# How to set max line in cat command

Tags: bash

in grep command I can set max line to output with parameter -m. How I can specify max line in cat command ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`cat` is dedicated to *whole* files.

You are looking for either `head` or `tail`, depending if your counting starts from the beginning or end of a file.

**Examples**

- `head --lines=100` print the first 100 lines
- `head --lines=-100` print all but the last 100 lines
- `tail --lines=100` print the last 100 lines
- `tail --lines=-100` print all but the first 100 lines

**Note**

You may also have a look at `tac`.
The result is clear, if you compare the word `tac` with `cat`.
`tac` prints out all lines in reverse ordering.

Comment: I want to println file from start. Thx head is what I looking for

Comment: @hudi updated answer should make it clear.

Answer (score 2):

Use `head -n $NUMBER_OF_LINES` instead of `cat`.

And watch out for useless uses of `cat`.

Comment: @hudi: Read the answer again.